# Поставить условие и изменить значение DataGridView cell.value

Tags: c#, winforms

Задача: поставить ограничения на вводимые данные в ячейки таблицы. Так, чтобы при выходе из ячейки, данные, которые мы ввели туда проверялись и изменялись при необходимости.
С некоторой помощью дошел до следующего кода:

```
private void data1_CellLeave(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        DataGridViewTextBoxCell cell = (DataGridViewTextBoxCell)data1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex];
        if (Convert.ToDouble(cell.Value) < (-99)) //с этой строкой ничего не работает
            cell.Value = -99;
    }
```

С `if` не работает вовсе, без него работает - при выходе из любой ячейки меняются данные на `-99`. Что не так с условием `if`?

Comment: а вы проверяли  значение _Convert.ToDouble(cell.Value)_?

Comment: Нет, но у нее же адрес ячейки, куда я ввожу свои данные для примера.

Comment: а вы попробуйте проверить

Comment: Как это правильно сделать?

Comment: поставить точку остановки на этой строчке и добавить это выражение в   панель Watch

Comment: Не совсем понял, как это сделать, прогнал так, по шагам)
Проблема была в том, что при выходе из ячейки, значение ячейки, было старое, не то, которое я вводил вручную.

Comment: Можете наверное добавить свой ответ, что нужно было подписываться на другое событие потому что то-то и то-то :-)

Comment: Да, добавлю завтра, спасибо:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как я понял, проблема в особенности данного события, оно не совсем подходит. 
Вот рабочий код, если заполнять таблицу вручную, данные фильтруются и исправляются:

```
private void data1_CellEndEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    DataGridViewTextBoxCell cell = (DataGridViewTextBoxCell)data1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex];
    if (Convert.ToInt32(cell.Value) <= -99)
        cell.Value = -99;
}
```

В `Cellleave` событии в качестве `cell.value` передавалось предыдущее значение ячейки. Т.е. при входе в ячейку ее значение было `5`, мы зашли и изменили значение на `-100`, вышли. В `cell.value` передалось `5`, а не `-100`, поэтому ячейка и не очищалась. Для похожих задач используйте событие `CellEndEdit` или `CellValidated`(данный код работает идентично в обоих событиях)